# Como insertar salto de linea en UNIQUE_COPY

Tags: c++

En entrada.txt tengo:

```
Linea numero uno
Linea numero dos
Linea numero tres
```

y en salida.txt obtengo:

```
Linea numero unoLinea numero dosLinea numero tres
```

Este es el código en C++ Version 11 o 14:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>

int main () {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "es_ES");
    string linea;  string tmp;
    ofstream salida; salida.open ("salida.txt");
    ifstream archivo; archivo.open ("entrada.txt");

    while (getline(archivo, linea)) {
        while(linea.size()) {
            unique_copy (linea.begin(), linea.end(), back_inserter(tmp), [](char c1, char c2){ return c1 == ' ' && c2 == ' '; }); break; } }
    salida <<  tmp << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema no es `unique_copy` sino `getline`. Esta función **elimina** el salto de línea. Así que lo que tienes que hacer es añadirlo manualmente.

Por otro lado, nota que la línea `while(linea.size())` no tiene demasiado sentido ya que no hay ningún camino que permita ejecutar más de una iteración del código del bucle... yo lo reemplazaría por un `if`:

```
while (getline(archivo, linea))
{
    if (!linea.empty())
    {
        linea += '\n'; // <<--- añadimos el salto de linea
        unique_copy (linea.begin(), linea.end(), back_inserter(tmp),
                     [](char c1, char c2){ return c1 == ' ' && c2 == ' '; });
    }
}
```

Comment: linea += '\n', añade al final de la línea, el "salto de línea" que fue eliminada por getline()